# Pytorch: Softmax on each row of a 2d Tensor

Tags: pytorch

I need my neural net to output N distributions over A actions. each distribution should go through softmax. The sum of each row should then obviously be 1 and the sum of the whole layer should be N. Is there such functionality in PyTorch?

Comment: Where is your code or preview or evidence to show your work on neural nets?

Comment: your question is not clear but you can see the softmax function available in PyTorch library.

Answer (score 1):

Use the softmax and specify the row as the dimension to operate on

```
import torch.nn.Functional as F

x = ...# your N x A input
x_distribution = F.softmax(x, dim = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easy to solve using transposing. Here is my solution:

```
data = torch.Tensor([[-0.4275,  2.0973],
    [ 0.4284,  0.9128],
    [ 0.1397,  1.3663],
    [-0.4221,  2.0760]])

res = torch.softmax(data.T, dim=0).T
```

Here we have:

```
tensor([[0.0741, 0.9259],
    [0.3812, 0.6188],
    [0.2268, 0.7732],
    [0.0760, 0.9240]])
```